# Elasticsearch: document relationship

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm doing a elastic search autocomplete-as-you-type
I'm using cool features like ngram's and other stuff to create needed analyzer.

currently I break my had around indexing following data.
Let say I have Payments type, 
each document in this type looks like this

```
{
 ..elastic meta data..
 paymentId: 123453425342,
 providerAccount : {
   id: 123456
   firstName: Alex,
   lastName: Web
 },
 consumerAccount : {
   id: 7575757,
   firstName: John,
   lastName: Doe
 },
 amount: 556,
 date : 342523454235345 (some unix timestamp)
}
```

so basically this document represents not only the payment itself but it also shows the relationship of the payment, the 2 entities which related to the payment. 
Payment always have its provider and consumer.
I need this data in payment document because I want to show it in UI.

By indexing it like so, it might be a big pain for handling the updates of Consumer or Provider because each time some of them change its properties I have to update all the payments which has this entity.

Another possible solution is to store only id's of this consumers/providers and make a query on payments and then 2 queries for the entities for retrieving needed fields, but i'm not sure about this because i'm doing ajax requests each time a character entered, so here comes the performance question.

I have also looked into parent/child relationship solution which basically fits my case but I wasn't able to figure out if I can retrieve also the parent(consumer/provider) fields while I querying child(payment).

What would you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: So what does the autocomplete suggest as you type? Names of providers/consumers? Payment ids?

Comment: In my case the orderId field has some value, its not just a generated uuid or string, so i want the user be able to type order id and get the suggestions.

Comment: each suggestion by the way must have the entire document. not only the autocompletion of the order id string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve the parent while querying child using `has_child`.
Considering `payment` as `child` and `consumer` as `parent`, You can search all the consumers by :

```
GET /index_name/consumer/_search
{
"query": {
"has_child": {
  "type": "payment",
  "query": {
    // any query on payment table
   },
   "inner_hits": {}
  }
 }
}
```

This would fetch you all the consumer based on the query on child i.e `payment` in your case.
`inner_hits` is what you are looking for. This will retrieve you the children as well. But it was introduced in elasticsearch `1.5.0`. So version should be greater than `elasticsearch 1.5.0`.
You can refer https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-5-0-released.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering :)
Is it also returns the payment(child) fields or only the consumer?
It looks that I'll get only consumer documents based on background filtering on payments type. Its not exactly what i looking for. I need some alternative which reminds rdbms join.

Comment: @alexander-roussakov I have edited my answer according to your requirements.Please verify it.

Comment: thanks so much for your effort. It seems to provide the end result which I expect. I will check this solution and if it works for me i'll respond here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not an issue. I suppose you want tot freeze data after the pay, right? So you don't need to update the accounts data in existing payment documents.

Further: parent/schild is easy for updating, but less efficient with querying. For auto complete, stay using your current mapping!

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering.
Nope i dont want freeze the data, i want be able to update the accounts data if it changes by other flows in the app.

Comment: Ok, but it's strange to save for each payment the consumer account data and provider account data. Maybe it's a solution for you to turn: nest the payment document (they never change?) in the provider account document and in the consumer account document.

Comment: Seems like a lot of payments document duplications, which also can be updated, even more frequently than a consumer/provider.